# How to send a welcome message personally to multiple users in MS Teams using Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

Does anyone know how I can send out welcome messages personally to multiple users when they are added to a channel, using power automate?

[image]
Here shows the manual way of adding recipient names, is there a way to make it dynamic?

Example:

User A is added to Channel X.
Power automate will trigger a message to be sent via Flow bot to User A MS Teams personal chat (Not channel)

Please advise if you know of any online guides as I have searched but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you cannot add more than one recipient at a time to that action.

A method I use is to create or use an array of email addresses from a source then use an Apply to Each  control to dynamically (using "Current Item") populate the recipient until all have been processed.  You will effectively be sending the same notice over and over but to different people each iteration.

I've attached an example where I append email addresses to an array variable, using results from a Get Items action (my source), then use the values of that array to send posts to individuals.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3jJp.png)